# aws api gateway and android sdk java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am having a prob since yesterday that my android project does not want to run anymore and i get this error as an output.

```
Process: com.example.liam.myapplication, PID: 23846
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory.getHandler(ApiClientFactory.java:145)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory.build(ApiClientFactory.java:123)
at com.example.liam.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Preconditions.checkArgument($Gson$Preconditions.java:42)
at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(GsonBuilder.java:448)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.<clinit>(ApiClientHandler.java:60)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory.getHandler(ApiClientFactory.java:145) 
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory.build(ApiClientFactory.java:123) 
at com.example.liam.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

i tried:

1. async block
2. just catch it and continue but the client.gpssaverPost(body) cannot be used on a null object

i already know this line of code is the problem:

```
final LambdaMicroserviceGPSSaverClient client = factory.build(LambdaMicroserviceGPSSaverClient.class);
```

and if i keep clicking on my error it stops at the apiKey but i don't have any API- key so i have no idea how to solve this.

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by regenerating the android sdk from aws api gateway. imported everything again and fixed my problem so probably an update that fixed this problem